# Why property of the function invisible when function imported to another file?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this function in file colled dataservice.js:

```
export function DataServices() {
    var that = this;
    that.dataServiceUrl = "/CrossServices/SearchService.svc";

    var ds = {
        getStreets: getStreets
    };
    return ds;

    function getStreets(expr, callback, error) {
        //some logic
        return result;
    }
}
```

I import function above in mapApp.js file like this:

```
    import { DataServices  from "/src/js/services/dataservices";
```

And try to access getStreets property this way:

```
        DataServices.getStreets(3, null, null);
```

But I get this error on the row above:

```
error:  Cannot read property 'getStreets' of undefined
```

Any idea why getStreets property not visible?

Comment: Use `import {DataServices}` instead...

Comment: Export a class instead of a nested function definition. But, your error message says `DataServices` is undefined, so you're not exporting it correctly. You'll either have to alias it with {}, or export a default function

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it should be `DataServices.DataServices().getStreets(3, null, null)` by the way you export that. Why don't you just `export function getStreets (){...}`

Comment: Your import/export doesn't match, is it `getStreets` or `getFeatures`, and where are you actually calling `DataServices()` to create the object?

Comment: You should not use `this` unless you call it as a method or with `new` as a constructor, and if you do call it as a constructor, you should not `return` an object literal

Answer (score 2):

You are exporting a named function `DataServices`

You need to make it the default export, or import it by name:

`export default function DataServices`

or

`import { DataServices } from "/src/js/services/dataservices";`

Comment: Matthew, thanks for the post. I tried  to make as you describe but I get the same error

Comment: Is your import path correct? `"/src/js/services/dataservices"` is importing from a top-level folder on the file system called `src`

Comment: yes, the path is correct. I put debugger keyword in dataservices.js and it triggered always after this  row is executed: import { DataServices } from "/src/js/services/dataservices";